# Redirect and cancel request using Interceptor when HttpStatus is 202

Tags: angular, angular-http-interceptors

I'm doing a web application using Angular 10.

In my authentication flow, if the backend sends HttpStatus 202 after you log in, means that you need to enter a pincode and I need to redirect you to another component. I have tried to do this using an Interceptor but, I am experiencing the following problems:

1. The redirection is not happening
2. I cannot find a way to cancel the request, in other words, let the owner of the request (LoginComponent) to know that it needs to do nothing because something else happened.

Interceptor

```
@Injectable()
export class AuthInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {

  constructor(
    private router: Router
  ) {
  }

  intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    return next.handle(request).pipe(
      filter(event => event instanceof HttpResponse),
      map((event: HttpResponse<any>) => {
        if (event.status === 202) {
          this.router.navigateByUrl('/validation-code');
        }
        return event;
      }));
  }

}
```

LoginComponent

```
@Component({
  templateUrl: './login.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./login.component.scss']
})
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(
    private authService: AuthService,
    private router: Router
  ) {
  }

  onSubmit() {
    this.authService.login('username', 'password')
      .pipe(first())
      .subscribe(() => this.router.navigate(['/']));
  }

}
```

AuthService

```
login(username: string, password: string): Observable<IUser> {
    const payload = {
      Username: username,
      Password: password,
    };

    return this.post<IUser>({
      url: '/login',
      body: payload
    })
      .pipe(
        tap(user => this.localStorageService.set('user', user)),
      );
  }
```

I have tried to modify the Interceptor like this:

```
intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    return next.handle(request).pipe(
      filter(event => event instanceof HttpResponse),
      map((event: HttpResponse<any>) => {
        if (event.status === 202) {
          this.router.navigateByUrl('/auth/validation-code');

          // I have tried these...
          // return of(undefined);
          // return EMPTY;
          // return NEVER;
        }
        return event;
      }));

  }
```

> TS2322: Type 'Observable<HttpResponse | Observable>' is
> not assignable to type 'Observable<HttpEvent>'.   Type
> 'HttpResponse | Observable' is not assignable to type
> 'HttpEvent'.     Type 'Observable' is not assignable to
> type 'HttpEvent'.       Property 'type' is missing in type
> 'Observable' but required in type 'HttpUserEvent'.

My goal is to handle my scenarios of authentication using an Interceptor and redirect the user to a component when I receives HttpStatus 202.

Answer (score 1):

You need to throw an error in order to stop the observable flow. Try this:

```
intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    return next.handle(request).pipe(
      filter(event => event instanceof HttpResponse),
      map((event: HttpResponse<any>) => {
        if (event.status === 202) {
          this.router.navigateByUrl('/auth/validation-code');
          throw new Error('Pin code required');
        }
        return event;
      }),
      catchError(err => {
        return of(err);
      })
    );
  }
```